# I can't extend a div in the correct direction with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a large header with a navigation bar within it. Once you reach the base of the header, the navigation bar becomes fixed at the top by itself leaving the header to scroll behind along with the remaining content. It snaps back into the header when you scroll up again. The functionality is perfect. I have two questions...

1. When it snaps at the top of the screen it becomes centered (which IS what I want), but it is only 500 pixels or so wide and I want the white background to extend beyond the buttons one either side to reach the edges of body (960px in width). When I changed the width, it only extended from the right hand side which then caused it to overlap off the edge of the page.
2. Even though it appears to be centred I am convinced that it is off by about 30 odd pixels. It may be a padding or margin setting???

THE WEIRDEST THING THOUGH, ONCE I PLACED THE CODE ONTO A WEB-SERVER FOR YOU TO TEST, THE NAVIGATION BAR DOESN'T CENTRE PROPERLY LIKE IT DOES WHEN I OPEN THE HTML FILE IN MY BROWSER... SO THERE'S A THIRD QUESTION? HOW DO I STOP IT FROM DOING THAT?

Thanks you and please help :)

The code is below but if you'd like to see it in action you may visit here (http://www.justletmeusethisnameplz.co.nf/).

Here is the relevant HTML

```
<div class="header"> <!-- BEGINNING OF HEADER -->

    <div id="logo"> <!-- BEGINNING OF LOGO -->

    <h1 class="sliding-middle-out">Hi</h1>

    </div> <!-- END OF LOGO -->

    <div id="navigation">  <!-- BEGINNING OF NAVIGATION -->

    <div style="float:right"> <!-- BEGINNING OF IDK -->

    <div id="slider"></div>
    <a href="index.html"><div id="one" class="item"><div class="inside">Home</div></div></a>
    <a href="about.html"><div id="two" class="item"><div class="inside">About Us</div></div></a>
    <a href="content.html"><div id="three" class="item"><div class="inside">Content</div></div></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><div id="four" class="item"><div class="inside">Contact</div></div></a>

    </div> <!-- END OF IDK -->

    </div> <!-- END OF NAVIGATION -->

    </div> <!-- END OF HEADER -->
```

Here is the relevant CSS

```
.header{
        height:100px;
        width:960px; 
        float:left;
        background-color:white;
      }
      #navigation{
        height:40px;
        font-size:20px;
        color:black;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        float:right;
        background-color:white;
        padding-top:5px;
        position:relative;
      }
      #navigation.stick{
        height:40px;
        font-size:20px;
        color:black;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        float:left;
        background-color:white;
        padding-top:5px;
        position:fixed;
      }
      .logo{
        height:100px;
        width:425px; 
        float:left;
      }
```

Here is the relevant JavaScript/ JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 1){
    $('#navigation').addClass("stick");
    }else{
    $('#navigation').removeClass("stick");
    }
});
</script>
```

AND YES I AM AWARE OF CALLED UPON MANY JQUERY LIBRARIES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you don't need jQuery for this.  CSS will take care of it.

Your first problem with width can be solved by adding `width:inherit;` to `#navigation.stick` which will apply the width of the parent (in this case the header at 960px) to the element.

The next problem is that the logo pushes the navigation over.  No problem, add this CSS:

```
#logo{
    position:absolute;
}
```

That will break it from the flow of the page and allow the navigation to move to the left.

Finally for centering.  You'll need some extra changes.

```
#navigation.stick{
    text-align:center;
}

#navigation.stick > div{
    float:none;
}
```

The only problem now will be that the slider effect over the menu might be broken because the menu is moving around but that'll be more involved to fix.

Comment: Hello, once I made those changes everything worked. Except... you were right. The changes I made ruined the navigation bar entirely. What do I do now?

Comment: Try this `#navigation.stick > div{ position:relative; }`

Comment: That made the slider move down from the top instead of that sticking to the top of page like it did before. O did I mention that the buttons are still stuck on the right and are not in the centre.

Comment: The center text align didn't work earlier but it did extend the bar to the sides like I wanted

Comment: For some reason a float is being applied to all of your divs.  That's why it wont center.  `#navigation.stick > div[style] {float:none !important;}` to force it to remove the float.

Comment: I made the changes and there was no change. If you don't believe me, please look at the css at the web link I provided 3 comments up

Comment: You need to add the `!important` to the end of the value.

Comment: I did. I added it to the float:none line. Is that the wrong line?

Comment: I see the `float:none;`  it needs to be `float:none !important;`

Comment: I tried to attach a screenshot of the F12 Developer Tools where I have shown that I have typed it

Comment: if it doesn't say the following at http://www.justletmeusethisnameplz.co.nf/index%20stacky.html on line line 86, it's wrong.  `#navigation.stick > div[style] {
    float: none !important;
    position: relative;
}`

Comment: I just checked, yes, line 86 has this exact coding `#navigation.stick > div[style] { float: none !important; position: relative; }`

Comment: Hang on I know what the prolem is I think

Comment: Ok I fixed it but it is still not centred, and the slider in the nav bar isn't stuck to the top of the page

Comment: `#navigation.stick{padding-top:0;}`

Comment: Ok that worked. Only one more thing an then I will tick your answer as correct. By the way thank you for being patient with me.

Comment: The navigation bar is still not centered. It is off by about 30 odd pixels

Comment: Not sure how to help you there, it's dead center on my screen.  I even measured it.

Comment: Ok. OMG I'm so sorry your right, it is because of the slider on the left, because it stuck out, it made the distance between it and the left look much shorter than the right. It is the same. I am SO Sorry! Thank you so much! You have been a great help! I will select your answer now :)

Comment: Hello again, could I please ask one more question

Comment: could you please help me once more